# Spike in TCP port 5904 activity - what for?

Tags: exploit, network-scanners, ports

There is an 'Internet Weather Report' on the Threat!Traq video blog by AT&T security researchers. In the March 14th broadcast, at around 31 minutes in, they mention an increase of scanning activity on port 5904/TCP. The researchers mention they do not know what is being scanned for.

Does anyone know what vulnerability (or use) the attacker(or benign user?) may be searching for?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what vulnerability they might be looking for, but VNC uses that port. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-iptables-open-vncserver-port-6000-5800-5900/

Maybe one of the vulnerabilities listed here that applies to VNC servers. http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=vnc

Comment: Yes, though, it's only likely that VNC will only be using 5904 in thin client systems. VNC main listen is on 5900 and it spawns a port for each display server sequentially up from that, so 5904 is not 'till the 4th display server.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes useful to scan a *closed* port (host discovery and fingerprinting).

Assuming TCP, VNC *may* use it, if you compare the *DShield* graphs for ports [5900](https://secure.dshield.org/port.html?port=5900), [5901](https://secure.dshield.org/port.html?port=5901), [5902](https://secure.dshield.org/port.html?port=5902), [5903](https://secure.dshield.org/port.html?port=5903) and [5904](https://secure.dshield.org/port.html?port=5904) there's some visible agreement between 5901, 5902, and 5904 but notably *not* with 5903. 5900 has too much background noise.

On a hunch, I compared permutations of ports, and found [5904](https://secure.dshield.org/port.html?port=5904) drops around when [5490](https://secure.dshield.org/port.html?port=5490) starts, but the number of target systems isn't comparable (`nmap` tells me port 5490 is a HTTP/CONNECT proxy, but fairly scarcely seen, in the bottom 1%). So much for my hunch of a misfired scanner.

I can tell you that I have recorded (logs only, not packet captures or honeypot data) recent scans targeting TCP/5900,5901,5902,5904 (*not* 5903). Discounting 5900 (since that's constantly scanned) from 25 unique hosts.

All the destination 5904 probes came (notionally) from a single IP registered to a large French web/virtual hosting company, 80% of the total port 590{1,2,4} probes in all. Over a 60+ hour period from March 7-11 every probe used the same four source/destination port pairs, with target port 5904 being approx 50% of total. Different target ports were favoured on different days and by different hosts, scans possibly started on March 6 with port 5901. A low-rate, non-sequential, non-uniform scan (from 10-30 probes per host) of an IP block was performed. I suspect it was also network mapping attempt because an upstream device (on a different IP block) also recorded the same scans (source host & port, destination ports) interleaved with those scans.

Best guess is a distributed parallelised scan for VNC ports (with a generous addition of lesser-used ports) via hijacked hosts, and perhaps they got lucky with a well connected system in the unnamed French ISP which skewed port 5904 statistics. I cannot explain the omission of port 5903.